# Travelling between two cities with cabs starting between

Tags: algorithm

> You want to get from town A to B being m miles apart using some number
>   of cabs. Somewhere between the towns (or in one of them) there's a cab
>   base (each cab starts its journey from the base). Each cab has fuel
>   for some miles of travel (none of the cabs has to return to the base).
>   Determine if your travel from A to B is possible.
>
> INPUT:
>
> Integers m,d,n (1<=d<=m<=10^8, 1<=n<=500,000) meaning (in that
>   order): distance from A to B, distance from A to cab base, number of
>   cabs. After that, n integers meaning that i-th cab has fuel for x_i-th
>   miles of travel.
>
> OUTPUT:
>
> One integer: a minimum number of cabs you'll have to use to
>   get from A to B or 0 if it's impossible.

I tried tackling it with what first stroke my mind and (not surprisingly) it wasn't that good of an idea. Namely, what I did was:

```
sort(ALL(cabs));
reverse(ALL(cabs));

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    toPosition = position <= d ? d-position : position - d;

    if(cabs[0] <= toPosition) {printf("0"); return 0;}

    position += (cabs[0]-toPosition);
    cabs.erase(cabs.begin());
    ++solution;

    if(position >= m) {printf("%lld", solution); return 0;}
}
```

Now, `toPosition` is the distance from the base to the current `position` we're in. Then, we take the cab with the fullest gas tank from the base (if there's none such that it could get us closer to town B, there's no solution). We change our `position` accordingly (to the max of given cab's capacities), remove the cab and just do it until we're in town B.

I now know that the solution is wrong. I even found some tests where it fails. However, I can't quite get why it does. So for example for test

```
14 4 2
10 8
```

It outputs 0 while it should output 2. I know that it's because it wants to go 10->8 while the correct order here is 8 -> 10. Now here's where the problem arises:

Why does the order matter here in this problem? If we have to cover all the distance from A to B anyway and until we're in or after the base location, we have to backtrack with each cab, why not use the ones which would do the backtracking mission the fastest?

Comment: Smells like homework. You should specify language in your tags

Comment: Smells like training on past problems from various programming contests. I didn't specify the language because it's hardly C++-related and the code I posted is so self explanatory that I reckoned it wouldn't be necessary. If more of you think I should add the C++ tag, why not, I'll do it.

Comment: I think you'll get more attention. Many people subscribe to the c++ tag so they will be notified of this question if they have opted in to receive updates.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you had 3 cabs, where only 1 has enough fuel to get to A, and it can get you 1 mile short of the base; one has enough fuel to get you from the base to B; and the last has enough fuel for a 2 mile trip.  Clearly, you have to use the "smallest" cab second; if you used the other, you'd be just shy of B, with a cab that can't reach you, much less finish the job.

So, yeah, the order does matter.

Answer (score 0):

- d: distance to cab base
- m: distance from A to B
- int[] cabMilliage: the miles that each cab can make

---

I figured one optimization strategy that you could use:
Start to construct your path 'backwards', from the last cab to the first.
To cover the distance from the cab base to B, you will use only one cab, there is no way to use more than one, so start by selecting this one. 
distBaseToB = m - d;
Select the minimum cabMilliage[i] >= distBaseToB

calculate the point where this cab pick you up
pickUpPoint[0] = d - (cabMilliage[i] - distBaseToB)/2
now, continue with a loop, selecting the minimum cabMilliage[] that can pick you up earlier in the path and bring you to pickUpPoint[0]
until you reach A (or run out of cabs that can pick you up at that point of the road because they don't have enough gas.)

Comment: I'm fairly positive your solution won't work just as mine doesn't because it's based on the same premise - that either the cab with the fullest tank currently available is going to be used whenever possible or there's no answer. The counterexample I and Scott Hunter provided clearly decline this attitude.

Comment: ah, got it! - we need some backtracking: a brute force solution is a function that selects a cab in each invocation and calls itself recursively with each of the remaining cabs, until it reaches B. I'm afraid that is O(n!), and it does not give the smallest number of cabs, but it answers the question of whether it is possible to reach B.